# Oracle SQL: Multiple IN statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very simple code to return multiple lines depending on the IN statement...

```
select cunr, name
    from oes_customer
    where cunr in ('W30053','W30054')
```

I will be running the code in BoXI and the IN statment will need to be changed so the person running the report will define the IN statement list via a report refresh.

e.g.

```
select cunr, name
    from oes_customer
    where cunr in @variable('CUNR')
```

The list could be as many as 20 items.

How do I write the IN statement so the person running the report can refresh using multiple 'cunr'?

I tried using chr functions plus @variable to give the same string as used in my first statement...

```
where cunr in chr(40)||chr(39)|| replace(@variable('CUNR'),' ',chr(39)||chr(44)||chr(39)) ||chr(39)||chr(41)

where cunr in '('''||replace(@variable(@variable('CUNR'),' ',chr(39)||chr(44)||chr(39)) ||''')'
```

...I did not get errors using this, but I also got no results?

Not sure if I'm even on the right track?!?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you

```
select cunr, name
    from oes_customer
    where concat(concat(',',@variable),',') like concat(concat(',',cunr),',')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply; when I use this code I get an ORA-00936: missing expression :-936 error

Comment: `concat` takes only two arguments. Rewrite this with `',' || cunr || ','` and similar for the other one.

Comment: I tried rewriting the code as where concat(',' || @variable('CUNR') || ',') like concat(',' || cunr || ',') but now I get the following error: invalid number of arguments

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but unfortunately, although I get no errors with this amended code, I also get no results. What should be entered in my refresh field ... should I separate multiple entries with a comma (e.g. W30053,W30054)?